# How to score a goal with Bicycle kick - FIFA 12?

Tags: fifa-12

I am trying hard to score a goal with the bicycle kick but it seems I am unable to perform the bicycle kick.

Does anyone know how to perform this maneuver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hold down the left trigger and spam  the sh*t out of the `B` button for XBox, or `Circle` if you're on PS3."

Comment: well thanks for the info.. but i am looking for xbox.. some moderator removed the tag i added in the question for xbox360...

Comment: @Dilberted It says "Circle if you're on the PS3". I included both the XBox and PS3 controls. If you watch the video it tells you for both.

Comment: @Dilberted The moderator was right to remove the XBox tag as a good answer should answer for both consoles.

Answer (score 0):

For XBOX use the LT+B For PS3 L2+O.Both usually works when you cross the ball.